# Why was this question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

My question [How can suffering from natural causes be reconciled with an omnimax god?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/why-is-there-suffering-from-natural-causes) was closed as a duplicate of [Are natural disasters the result of evil being allowed into our world?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/are-natural-disasters-the-result-of-evil-being-allowed-into-our-world).

I don't think those questions are duplicates.

- My question is about more than natural disasters, it also includes other natural causes, e.g. illnesses.
- My question is about the theodicy, it is about reconciling the omni-attributes of god with the suffering on earth. The other is about biblical references.

The topics are similar, but the answers to the second question won't really answer my question. They are about the scriptural justification of natural disasters, they don't involve the contradictions with the omnimax nature of god.

I'd like to either have someone convince me that I'm wrong and the questions should be closed as duplicates, or if you're not convinced please consider reopening the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've re-opened; the two questions are related, but I rather suspect the original could work better as a follow-up to yours; right now, the answers are a bit tangential (I suspect folks really *want* to answer a question more like the one you asked).

Answer (score 0):

It was closed because the answers given in the first question could have been applied to your question equally.

Comment: But those answers don't really answer my question because they are  not about the contradiction with the omnimax nature of the christian god. They give scriptural referenced for the source of natural disasters, they don't say how natural disasters can be reconciled with the omnimax nature of god.